# Filtering data in columns from options use jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I work with filtering, and i have issues, i have 4 option input in which i have some data which i need to filter in table, for now i filter data only for one column, but problem is if i will add one more filter, script will not work, and filter data from the last selected value. But i need if i have 2-4 selected values in option data is filtering.

My code:
JS:

```
$("#cancelFilters").hide();

$('#filterButton').click(function () {
    getSelectedVal()
    filterData()
    filters = [];
    $("#cancelFilters").fadeIn();
});

var filters = [];

function getSelectedVal() {
    var materialCode = $('#materialCode option:selected').text()
    var plantCode = $('#plantCode option:selected').text()
    var vsCode = $('#vsCode option:selected').text()
    var status = $('#statusCode option:selected').text()

    applyFilter(materialCode, 1)
    applyFilter(plantCode, 2)
    applyFilter(vsCode, 3)
    applyFilter(status, 4)
}

function applyFilter(value, id) {
    if (value)
        filters.push('.column' + id + ':contains(' + value + ')');
}


function filterData() {
    if (filters.length > 0) {
        var rows = $("#orderListData").find("tr").hide();

        filters.forEach(filter => {
            $("#orderListData td" + filter).parent().show();
        })

    }
}

$('#cancelFilters').click(function () {
    var $rows = $('#orderListData tr');
    $rows.show()
    $("#cancelFilters").fadeOut();
});
```

JSFIddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/k3ygL07f/11/

So if in options number 3 u will chosse **023** and tap add filters it's will work, but if i chosse **023** and options number 4 **BOOKED** it's will filter only booked status, where is problem?

Comment: From that fiddle it appears to be applying an OR filter.  If I add 023 and booked I get results that include 023 OR booked records.  https://imgur.com/a/rGNPzrH

Comment: @NathanChampion for now i just filter for one column this is working, but i case if i want add 1 ore more filter it's will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing  `$("#orderListData td" + filter).parent().show()` on every filter, you are essentially showing every row that matches EVEN ONE of the filters. While you have to show only those rows which can satisfy ALL filters.

So instead of looping through `filters` and checking if any `td` element satisfies it, loop through the `rows` and check if it satisfies every filter.

Use this code to do so ( Only the `filterData` function is changed )

```js
    $("#cancelFilters").hide();

    $('#filterButton').click(function () {
      getSelectedVal()
      filterData()
      filters = [];
      $("#cancelFilters").fadeIn();
    });

    var filters = [];

    function getSelectedVal() {
      var materialCode = $('#materialCode option:selected').text()
      var plantCode = $('#plantCode option:selected').text()
      var vsCode = $('#vsCode option:selected').text()
      var status = $('#statusCode option:selected').text()

      applyFilter(materialCode, 1)
      applyFilter(plantCode, 2)
      applyFilter(vsCode, 3)
      applyFilter(status, 4)
    }

    function applyFilter(value, id) {
      if (value)
        filters.push('.column' + id + ':contains(' + value + ')');
    }


    function filterData() {
      if (filters.length > 0) {
        var rows = $("#orderListData").find("tr");
        rows.hide();
        
        //Check if any row satisfy all filters 
        $.each(rows, (i, row) => {
          if (filters.every(filter => $(row).find(filter).length)) {
            $(row).show();
          }
        })

      }
    }

    $('#cancelFilters').click(function () {
      var $rows = $('#orderListData tr');
      $rows.show()
      $("#cancelFilters").fadeOut();
    });
```

```css
    .row {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .row::after {
      display: table;
      clear: both;
      content: "";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for ...""></div>

        <div class=" col-2">
      <select class="form-control secondary-select" id="materialCode">
        <option></option>
        <option>16014344C</option>
        <option>16016398A</option>
        <option>16009838A</option>
      </select>
      <p><strong>Material Code</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <select class="form-control secondary-select" id="plantCode">
        <option></option>
        <option>0119</option>
        <option>0379</option>
      </select>
      <p><strong>Plant Code</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <select class="form-control secondary-select" id="vsCode">
        <option></option>
        <option>023</option>
        <option>0379</option>
      </select>
      <p><strong>Value Stream Code</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <select class="form-control secondary-select" id="statusCode">
        <option></option>
        <option>BOOKED</option>
        <option>RELEASED</option>
      </select>
      <p><strong>Status</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button id="filterButton" class="button button-clear butt-heith">
        Apply filters
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="cancelFilters" class="button button-deactivate float-right">
    Cancel filters
  </button>

  <table class="table-editor" id="ordersList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Production order code</th>
        <th>Material code</th>
        <th>Target quantity</th>
        <th>Plant code</th>
        <th>Value stream code</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Release date</th>
        <th>Activation date</th>
        <th>Booking date</th>
        <th>TPT (d)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orderListData">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20943">14298947</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11027174A
        </td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 06:57:42
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:12:22
        </td>
        <td>
          0.1 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20944">80150671</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11019682A
        </td>
        <td>
          800
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:02:32
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-02 15:30:51
        </td>
        <td>
          0.3 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20945">80150672</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          15000987A
        </td>
        <td>
          503
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">

        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:28:04
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-13 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          10.6 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20946">80150673</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11011572E
        </td>
        <td>
          153
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:30:32
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-06 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          3.6 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20947">80150674</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          18300753C
        </td>
        <td>
          153
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">

        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:30:57
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-10 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          7.6 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20948">80150675</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11014966C
        </td>
        <td>
          153
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          RELEASED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:31:26
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20949">80150676</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11014264D
        </td>
        <td>
          79
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">

        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:33:48
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-06 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          3.6 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20950">80150677</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          18300753C
        </td>
        <td>
          79
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:34:16
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-10 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          7.6 </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20951">80150678</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          11020109B
        </td>
        <td>
          79
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">

        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          RELEASED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:34:38
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td></td>
        <td>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="/ProductionOrderManagement/ProductionOrderOperations?productionOrderId=20952">80150679</a>
        </td>
        <td class="column1">
          15001454B
        </td>
        <td>
          100
        </td>
        <td class="column2">

        </td>
        <td class="column3">
          023
        </td>
        <td class="column4">
          BOOKED
        </td>
        <td>
          2020-03-02 08:37:59
        </td>

        <td></td>

        <td>
          2020-03-12 00:00:00
        </td>
        <td>
          9.6 </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```